# Whenever I run a program in Python Shell I get a line that says RESTART: C:\... $

Tags: python, shell, anaconda

Whenever I run a program in Python Shell I get a line that says `RESTART: C:\... $`.

Restarting the program, using programs that did not have this issue in the past etc. do not seem to do anything. Thanks in advance for any advice!

**What is causing this?**

[image: Image of the issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line means that the `.py` file has been executed in the python shell.

It's a log statement to explicitly declare that your namespace is being cleared and the file is going to be ran fresh again.

> In simple words: The IDLE internally restarts itself before executing
>   your program, thus clearing all the information above so the variables
>   from earlier programs will not mess with your program

.